# What is wrong with this proof that $h^\vee$ the dual Coxeter number is always 1?

Tags: group-theory, definition, conventions, representation-theory, lie-algebra

(Not putting this in the math stack exchange because this is all about structure constants which are more familiar to physicists.)

Say we have the basis of a Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ with dimension $\dim(\mathfrak{g}) = d$ satisfying
$$
[T^a, T^b] = f^{ab}_{\;\;\;c} T^c.
$$
We define the symmetric bilinear Killing form
$$
\kappa(X, Y) = \mathrm{Tr}_\mathfrak{g}(\mathrm{ad}_X \mathrm{ad}_Y)
$$
and assume it is invertible. This defines the components
$$
\kappa^{ab} = \kappa(T^a, T^b).
$$
A standard computation reveals
$$
\kappa^{ab} = f^{ac}_{\;\;\;d}f^{bd}_{\;\;\;c}.
$$
We also define $\kappa_{ab}$ to be the inverse of this matrix. This means that
$$
 \kappa^{ab}\kappa_{bc} = \delta^{a}_c
$$
and
$$
\kappa^{ab}\kappa_{ba} = d.
$$
Using the inverted Killing form we can define the quadratic Casimir element
$$
C = \kappa_{ab} T^a T^b
$$
and we can check that it does indeed commute with all $T^c$'s. By Schur's lemma this means that it takes a constant value on any irreducible representation, including the adjoint representation $\mathrm{ad}_{\mathfrak{g}}$.
$$
C \cdot T^c = \# \delta^c_e T^e.
$$
I have been told (?) that this number, the value of the quadratic Casimir in the adjoint representation, is equal to something called the dual Coxeter number.
$$
\# = h^\vee.
$$
So, if we compute
\begin{align}
C \cdot T^c &= \kappa_{ab} [T^a, [T^b, T^c]] \\
&= \kappa_{ab} f^{bc}_{\;\;\;d} [T^a, T^d] \\
&= \kappa_{ab} f^{bc}_{\;\;\;d} f^{ad}_{\;\;\;e} T^e. 
\end{align}
This seems to me to imply that
$$
h^\vee \delta^c_e = \kappa_{ab} f^{bc}_{\;\;\;d} f^{ad}_{\;\;\;e}.
$$
However, if we contract $c$ and $e$ then this equation becomes
\begin{align}
h^\vee d &= \kappa_{ab} f^{bc}_{\;\;\;d} f^{ad}_{\;\;\;c} \\
&= \kappa_{ab} \kappa^{ba} \\
&= d
\end{align}
which means that $h^\vee = 1$.

Where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard definition of the Killing form is, as a matter of fact (cf. ref 1)
$$
\kappa(X,Y)=\frac{1}{2h^\vee}\operatorname{tr}(\operatorname{ad}X\operatorname{ad}Y)\tag{13.13}
$$
which includes an explicit factor of $h^\vee$. (This definition is convenient because it makes $\kappa$ independent of conventions for how traces are normalized. The factor of 2 is because we usually fix longs root to $|\theta|=2$, with $\theta$ the highest weight of the adjoint representation.)

The computation in the OP now reproduces the expected result (cf. ref 1 §13.2.3).

**References.**

1. Francesco, Mathieu, Senechal - *Conformal field theory*.

Comment: So it is as simple as that the way I defined the quadratic Casimir $C$ is not the same as how most people do? Are you saying that the standard definition would be $C'$ where $C' = 2 h^\vee C$, at which point $\# = 2 h^\vee$...?

Comment: @user1379857 The Casimir is fine; it is the Killing form what needs revision.

Comment: Right, and they're related the way I defined it when I wrote $C = \kappa_{ab} T^a T^b$, where $\kappa_{ab}$ is the inverse Killing form